# Field Injection using Kotlin Language is not generating DaggerComponent

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger

I am trying to learn MVVM using Kotlin Language. I am facing some issue, kindly please help. I already searched on google, but not found any answer.

Points

1. When I used the Constructor Injection it is working fine and generating DaggerComponent class and the object is created.
2. When I Changed the Constructor injection to Field Injection, the DaggerComponent Class is not generating and throws some error.

**Using Constructor Injection**

```
lateinit var car: Car

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val component = DaggerCarComponent.create()
    car = component.getCar()
    car.drive()
}
```

Here DaggerCarComponet is generated and car object is created via dagger, and also able to call drive() method of car class.

**Using Field Injector**

```
@Inject lateinit var car: Car

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val component = DaggerCarComponent.create()
    //car = component.getCar()
    component.inject(this)
    car.drive()
}
```

In the above I only added the `@Inject` annotation on the field and then calling the inject() method of CarComponent interface. But This is not working and throwing error as soon as I added `@Inject` annotation on **lateinit var car:Car**

**Here is the error**

> Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

> Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

**Here is the build.gradle(app)**

```
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.35.1'
//implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.21' // if you use the support libraries
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.21'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.28.3'

kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.21'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.28.3'
```

**build.gradle(Project)**

```
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.20"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is to annotate you Car class with @AndroidEntryPoint and then try field injection.

More info you can find here: https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#not-supported